# Not showing list in angular2 and asp core

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have Angular 2 app with Web API 2 in Asp.Net Core.

My angular service create a 9 column but not showing name or description of the item in angular html file.

what's the problem ? how can I solve this problem?

Interface :

```
export interface IRecipe {

    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
    Iamge: string;

}
```

Service :

```
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { IRecipe } from "./IRecipe"
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()

export class RecipeService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private url: string = "http://localhost:2560/api/sampledata/RecipesList";
    getStudentList() {
        let data: Observable<IRecipe[]> = this.http.get(this.url)
            .map(res => <IRecipe[]>res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
        return data;
    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

Ts :

```
import { RecipeService } from "./Service/RescipeService";
import { IRecipe } from "./Service/IRecipe";
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'Recipes',
    template: require('./Recipes.html'),
    styles: [require('./Recipes.css')]
})

export class RecipesComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private recipesservice: RecipeService) { }

    recipes: IRecipe[];
    errormessage: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.recipesservice.getStudentList()
            .subscribe(
            recipes => this.recipes = recipes,
            error => this.errormessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

Html :

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe.Name}}</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">{{recipe.Description}}</p>
        </div>
        <!--<span class="pull-right">
            <img class="img-responsive"
                 src="{{recipe.Image}}"
                 style="max-height: 50px;" />
        </span>-->
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
    Recipes Detail
</div>
```

**Update**

Web Api :

```
  [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<Recipes> RecipesList()
    {
        List<Recipes> recipes = new List<Recipes>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            Recipes res = new Recipes();
            res.Id = i;
            res.Name = string.Format("Kisnoush {0}", i + 1);
            res.Description = "It's Very Good Book . you Must Read it";
            res.Image="Image";
            recipes.Add(res);
        }
        return recipes;
    }
```

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: @Dipak it not show me error

Comment: see in the console log in browser(chrome F12, IE F12), or post your   Web API interface as well

Comment: i using this code for console.log but it not show me any thing :`constructor(private recipesservice: RecipeService) {

        console.log(this.recipes);
    }`

Comment: do console.log check whether you received excepted json

Comment: @Jonnysai  Update Question

Comment: @Dipak .Update Question

Comment: You need to look in the network tab of your browser to see how the data is coming back. My guess is that the json return object is lowercasing the property names so in your view you probably want `{{recipe.name}}` instead of `{{recipe.Name}}`.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment thank you. I find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this interface uppercase but JSON return lowercase, for this reason, it

not show me any things. I write the interface by lowercase it solved.

Json :

```
  [{"id":0,"name":"Kisnoush 1","description":"It's Very Good Book . you Must Read it","image":"Image"}
,{"id":1,"name":"Kisnoush 2","description":"It's Very Good Book . you Must Read it","image":"Image"}
,{"id":2,"name":"Kisnoush 3","description":"It's Very Good Book . you Must Read it","image":"Image"}
,{"id":3,"name":"Kisnoush 4","description":"It's Very Good Book . you Must Read it","image":"Image"}
,{"id":4,"name":"Kisnoush 5","description":"It's Very Good Book . you Must Read it","image":"Image"}
,{"id":5,"name":"Kisnoush 6","description":"It's Very Good Book . you Must Read it","image":"Image"}
,{"id":6,"name":"Kisnoush 7","description":"It's Very Good Book . you Must Read it","image":"Image"}
,{"id":7,"name":"Kisnoush 8","description":"It's Very Good Book . you Must Read it","image":"Image"}
,{"id":8,"name":"Kisnoush 9","description":"It's Very Good Book . you Must Read it","image":"Image"}
,{"id":9,"name":"Kisnoush 10","description":"It's Very Good Book . you Must Read it","image":"Image"
}]
```

interface :

```
    export interface IRecipe {

    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    image: string;

}
```